# Android studio doesn't recognise source folders

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm using a standard Android Studio directory structure and I created different build types:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        runProguard false
        packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    preview.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
    preview {
        packageNameSuffix ".preview"
    }
    release {
        runProguard false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

everything compiles fine, but AS doesnt recognize all of the source folders.
Only folders under `main` and `debug` are marked as source, folders under `preview` and `release` are displayed as normal folders
In effect there is no error checking in those folders

[image]

I checked the .iml file and sourceFolder tags were not added.

If I edit the project iml file manually adding the lines:

```
 <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/preview/java" isTestSource="false" />
 <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/preview/res" type="java-resource" />
```

It seems to work fine.

[image]

...until I sync with my gradle file - which removes the above lines.

Is this a bug in gradle plugin, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I hope you understand, that you should never edit the *.iml file, as it is generated from Gradle. Does the project correctly build from the commandline? If it doesn't the import might fail and the project model won't update. I'm not sure if you actually need the 'initWith' line by the way.

Comment: I just edited the iml file to see if this is the reason. So my conclusion is that it's not generated correctly.

Comment: The project compiles both from command line and from Studio - it just does show the folders as sourceFolders - which actually makes the work really difficult

Comment: OK, fair enough, do the build types show up in the build variant list?, I actually think that the answer from Ladios below is what you are looking for, only one build type will be active in the IDE.

Comment: anyone looking for android studio flavors demo

Comment: I also had this and had "Package name does not correspond..." errors on code inspection for files in different build variants. Very annoying.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You have to switch it in the build variants list, then AS will pick up the appropriate source sets.
[image: build variants]

Comment: Still I hope that in future AS will be able to see sources for different variants - it is a bit annoying that if I need to do a small change in different variant I have to manually switch

Comment: Agreed, every build-variant should be recognized and immediately displayed as such, this is very confusing!

Comment: It did not work for me even after doing all this. I am getting trouble importing classes in the common src package which I include in 2 custom flavors. Project compiles successfully its just in Android Studio editor that I see errors because of import issues.

Comment: @Ladios Jonquil. God bless you. And I'm not religious so it means more

Answer (score 3):

First, try re-importing the project. Delete all of your build directories, `.iml` files and the `.idea` folder. Then import the project.

If that doesn't work then you can try this to "force it".
[Checkout this response from Bernd Bergler.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/v0AluPBcoy0/KXR7oOmRQZIJ) **Note that this is a hack and ideally isn't necessary**

Here's a slightly modified version of his code.

```
task addPreview {
    def src = ['src/preview/java']
    def file = file("app.iml")

    doLast {
        try {
            def parsedXml = (new XmlParser()).parse(file)
            def node = parsedXml.component[1].content[0]
            src.each {
                def path = 'file://$MODULE_DIR$/' + "${it}"
                def set = node.find { it.@url == path }
                if (set == null) {
                    new Node(node, 'sourceFolder', ['url': 'file://$MODULE_DIR$/' + "${it}", 'isTestSource': "false"])
                    def writer = new StringWriter()
                    new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer)).print(parsedXml)
                    file.text = writer.toString()
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // nop, iml not found
        }
    }
}

// always do the addPreview on prebuild
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    preBuild.dependsOn(addPreview)
}
```

Simply drop that in your `build.gradle` file outside of the `android` section.
[Description from this source](http://blog.futurice.com/android_unit_testing_in_ides_and_ci_environments):

> Android Studio automatically generates .iml project files from gradle
>   build files. This task edits the Android Studio project file app.iml
>   and adds the test directory. The changes are lost whenever Android
>   Studio rescans the gradle files, but right after that it runs a build
>   and the task is hooked into that, so it’s all good. This version has a
>   couple of tweaks, such as adding the new task into the normal build
>   cycle a bit differently, and gracefully handling the absence of the
>   .iml file.

This has worked to an extent for me: The IDE recognizes it as a src tree now but doesn't want to link it with any other src trees.

Comment: ...which basically comes down to hacking the *.iml file which is a gross hack.

Comment: Not disagreeing with you.

Comment: Great :) Now lets cross our fingers this won't get accepted or upvoted.

Comment: Well, I don't mean to bicker, but it's a solution for an issue that doesn't really exist. In AS, you select the source folders based on the build type. Different build type / flavor effectively means different code. So it doesn't make sense to add other folders than the active build type to the IDE classpath. If you really need to add custom code to the build path, the 'correct' way would be through the extension points that the Android Gradle plugin provides.

Comment: The more I see this question the more I believe that I was quick to post this answer. It solves a very specific problem, for now, and this question is slightly different than what I aimed to answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my case only **File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart** have helped me, so if solutions above does not work for you - try this.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your module's build.gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/preview/java'
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/release/java'
}
```

Comment: I tried this - it did add both to the source tree, once I added the sourceSets group under the "android" group in my build.gradle file.  However, my project has Foo.java in both build flavors, so this trick ultimately didn't work, because the compiler complains about two source files with the same name.