# Creating test folders in legacy Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, testing, junit

I've been having issues getting test folders adding to my existing legacy project. I've been looking through Stack and whilst these users are all having similar issues, the solutions haven't yet worked. I'm new at working with gradle, so this has been a bit confusing.

[How to add test folders to an older Android Studio Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012717/how-to-add-test-folders-to-an-older-android-studio-project)

[Android studio doesn't recognise source folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068731/android-studio-doesnt-recognise-source-folders)

[Cannot Create Testing Folders In Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977322/cannot-create-testing-folders-in-android-studio)

The problem can be seen below:

[When looking at android view, I get this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYhyf.png)
You can see that there's a visible alpha and main folder.

[Looking at project view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVGps.png), you can see the addition of the `src/test/java` and `src/androidTest/java` to the folder structure, but I can't get them to register in Android view.

I've tried setting the sourceSets in the gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    beta {
        java.srcDirs = [ 'src/general/java']
        res.srcDirs=['src/general/res']
    }
    general {
        java.srcDirs = [ 'src/general/java', 'src/androidTest/java/', 'src/test/java']
        res.srcDirs=['src/general/res']
    }
    demo {
        java.srcDirs = [ 'src/alpha/java']
        res.srcDirs=['src/alpha/res']
    }
    alpha {
        java.srcDirs = [ 'src/alpha/java', 'src/androidTest/java/', 'src/test/java']
        res.srcDirs=['src/alpha/res']
    }

    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
    }

    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java']
    }

}
```

where test and androidTest are new. (Note: the others all have buildflavors associated with them, and I haven't created any for the tests. Could this be the issue?)

Some of the previous suggestions have said it's to do with build version and that there should be a testing related dropdown - [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6OIn.png). I've tested all of the builds with no success.

Another user suggested using the build task `assembleAndroidTest` to generate the folders, which gives the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':library:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.

  > Android resource linking failed

I've been having other issues with trying to get testing working whilst following through google's recommended documentation. Dependencies and manifest declarations have worked fine but trying to add

```
useLibrary 'android.test.runner'
useLibrary 'android.test.base'
useLibrary 'android.test.mock'
```

I get

> Error:Unable to find optional library: android.test.runner

Which I've seen referenced for apache legacy but little for this situation. I think this is probably a different problem but included it in case it was relevant.

Android studio is at version 3.2.1.

So in summary:

How do I add test folders to the project and get them to display in Android view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. A simple fix.

Inside the main, the folder structure was

> ```
> main/java/com/windowmaker/measure
> ```

and the folder structure for my test folders was

> ```
> test/java
> ```

By changing the path to

> `test/java/com/windowmaker/measure`

it now displays correctly.

[Hooray!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ4vn.png)